# Mentioning Works in Documents without a Bibliography

Tags: best-practices

In English class, I was taught to set book titles and other long works in italics. Since LaTeX seems to be very much about styling based on the meaning of the text, rather than declaring the style explicitly, is there a best practice way to mark up books, articles, and other works?  I'm usually not using a bibliography for my short documents, so I am just looking for an in-line markup that doesn't require a bibliography file.

I might write something like this:

> You'll find this theme throughout each of Mark Twain's works, but it is most pronounced in *Huckleberry Finn* and *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court*, but it is also prominent in his speech "The Horrors of the German Language".

I'm currently using `\textit{Book Title}` for books and long works, and quotes for short works and chapters, which works fine.  I'm just interested to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Typically you should use `\emph` and not `\textit` for this. For a more general version of your question see [\emph or \textit](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980).

Comment: Welcome! I don't understand why the length of your document affects the need for a bibliography. If you reference sources, you need to give the details even if the document is only one sentence. If you don't use any sources, you don't need a bibliography even if the document is a thousand pages.

Comment: @cfr There are many types of non-academic writing where a bibliography would be completely out of place, but you still might need to refer to other works. Think of a typical book review in a newspaper, for example.

Comment: @AlanMunn I assumed from the reference to `in English ...` that this was academic. Also, I checked the OP's profile which says they are a student at Texas A & M . Even if not, I'd still use a bibliography package such as Biblatex. I just wouldn't use `\printbibliography`. I certainly produce documents in which I say `\citetitle{}` and `\citeauthor{}` but never `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @AlanMunn In any case, my main point was that the *length* of a document isn't relevant. As you say, the *type* of document may be. My students often think that if an assignment is short or they don't have many sources, they don't need a bibliography. They think this even when the instructions state that a bibliography is required right at the beginning along with the word count and due date etc.

Comment: @cfr Of course, you're quite right. I suppose what I meant was more that for the type of writing I was doing, I was not citing sources academically, but merely mentioning the names of works as part of the document. This was a homework assignment asking for the names of some books that might have the answer to the problem presented. I know that all referenced sources need to be cited, regardless of the length of the document. In this case, I was inquiring from a style standpoint, since LaTeX didn't exist when *The Elements of Style* was published ^_^

Comment: @cfr I realized that I was unclear in my question statement. What I intended to convey is that I don't use a formal bibliography *package* on short documents.

Comment: @JonathanMoore Oh, right. That's very different. I would because I'm lazy, but that's just me ;).

Answer (score 2):

Declare macros for your two kinds of markup. For instance:

```
\newcommand*{\btitle}[1]{\emph{#1}} % for books
\newcommand*{\otitle}[1]{"#1"}      % for other texts
```

If later you want to change the style just change the macro(s).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\newcommand*{\otitle}[1]{``#1''}`?

Comment: And it will still only be correct for US English etc. - not for UK English and many other languages.